# Prevent pause while recording a video with intent on some Android devices

Tags: android, android-intent, video, recording

Is it possible to prevent such feature in selected devices (like the HTC One)?
I am starting an intent using that code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(/* path to some file */);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // set the video image quality to high
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 45); // limit the camera to 45 seconds

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I cannot find any flag to use for preventing "pause while recording"..
The stock Android camera (on api lvl21+ at least) there isn't any option to pause the video recording but on some devices you can.

Comment: Are you wants Pause Function Feature  Video Recording in Your Project ?

Comment: No I want to prevent it entirely in my app. that feature isn't available in all Android devices. i don't even think its an Android feature at all...